# Referencing an ID of a <ul> in CSS does not apply any inline styling. Trying to understand the reasoning behind this

Tags: html, css

This is my html for this particular section:

```
<nav id="TopNav">
      <ul id="Menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

I have given nav an id of TopNav and the ul an id of Menu.  I'm trying to have my li items be listed horizontally.

This is my CSS for the section above:

```
#TopNav {
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #414141;
}

li {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Now if I change the li to reference the id "Menu" in my css it doesn't apply the inline display style, however if I leave it at li, it will display it.  What if I potentially add another li to my html that I don't want the li styling from the css to apply to that which is why I gave the current one an ID.  Is there's a reason this is happening? How do I fix it or what is a good workaround for it?

Comment: If you change li to #Menu you are applying the styling to ul now, not li; you’d need to change li to #Menu li for it to stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be as explicit as you can be when writing your selectors.

In this case, you could identify the correct li elements by ensuring that they are the ones that are in Topnav AND in that particular list.

```css
#TopNav {
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #414141;
}

#TopNav #Menu li {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="TopNav">
      <ul id="Menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

There are several things you can select on, not just element types and class names. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for more details.

Comment: Thanks, did not know I could select multiple ID's and an element.  Good to know!